# Why does websphere 8.5 try to override javax-xml-bind using springframework-oxm-jaxb?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, websphere, websphere-8

Hi I have developed a web application to marshall and unmarshall using Jaxb2Marshaller from springframework OXM. The web application is working in tomcat without any issues. But when I tried in Websphere 8.5 I got the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "javax/xml/bind/attachment/AttachmentMarshaller.addMtomAttachment(Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;" during creation of class "org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller$Jaxb2AttachmentMarshaller": loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@78cb589a" of class "org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller$Jaxb2AttachmentMarshaller" and loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@9fb13ddf" of class "javax/xml/bind/attachment/AttachmentMarshaller" have different types for the method signature`

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.